# How to handle cookies with Azure AD authentication, Apache Reverse Proxy and Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, apache, tomcat, cookies, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular App with a Spring Boot Backend. I use "azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter" for the authentication via Azure AD. Everything works fine locally.
After the successful external (azure) login "https://local.../login/oauth2/code/azure?code=..." is called.
The request headers on this request contain authorization cookies from azure and the response header contains two "set-cookie"-entries: JSESSIONID, XSRF-TOKEN
After that request the user is logged in as expected.

With the production setup however it seems, that cookies are not set successfully.
The application runs on a Tomcat 9 behind a apache reverse proxy. The azure login itself is successful.
Also the request headers contain the two cookies, however "set-cookie" is not set. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide the code?